# Calculadora en android studio.Error método mainactivity

Tags: android

Quería saber porque no puedo ejecutar el MainActivity de ésta calculadora, los metodos onclick son de propiedad @override?
     MainActivity.java: http://pastebin.com/uBUKbTC0
     activity_main.xml: http://pastebin.com/3eV5zVJC
     strings.xml: http://pastebin.com/R7JcXkNA

Estoy usando android studio.

Comment: Hola @Diego. Por favor agrega el código relevante en la pregunta. No dependas de sitios externos para explicar tu problema.

Comment: No puedes ejecutar, te refieres a que marca error? especifica tu error o problema, pueden ser varias las razones para este problema. Es importante agregues el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat.

Comment: me dice que las variables no estan definidas en el scope. Pero estan definidas las 5, son de tipo Button en el mainactivity.     Por ejemplo asi estan                                                                                                     Button btnmulti=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnMultiplicacion);

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta parte del código y quita el cierre de llaves.

```
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```